# Java string split with Multiple Characters Delimiter

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a very complicated output from a function, which i need to use specific word from it.

For *example*, my **output** is:

```
 oracle   11257     1  0 14:01 ?        00:00:00 ora_pmon_sas
```

I need to get just "`sas`" word, which is next to "`ora_pmon_`"

**Another example:**

```
oracle   6187     1  0 13:41 ?        00:00:00 ora_pmon_db2
```

I need to get "`db2`". So what should be my expression?

**JAVA code:**

```
insArray=line.split("what will be between these quotes?");
```

Comment: why are you splitting it if that pattern occurs only once!..does it have multiple such patterns..Please be very specific with your question..

Comment: `input.substring(input.lastIndexOf('ora_pmon_') + 1)` will do the trick...

Comment: well, there may be another word like "asm_pmon_" instead of "ora_pmon_". But the rest of thing is similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do

```
String sub = s.substring(s.indexOf("ora_pmon_") + 9);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this one?

```
string = string.replaceAll(".*?ora_pmon_", "");
```

If you want multiple words in place of *ora*, then it will be

```
string = string.replaceAll(".*?(ora|kf|asm)_pmon_", "");
```

Comment: that could be useful but "ora" can be anything like "kf" or "asm". so what's your answer to that case?

Comment: replace ora with `(ora|kf|asm)` Just add your words there with a pipe in between.

Comment: but i only need to find them. if there is no words like "ora_pmon_sas", it should pass it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [String#substring(int i)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) combined with [String#lastIndexOf(char ch)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29)

For example:

```
String result = input.substring(input.lastIndexOf('_') + 1)
```

Comment: What about `ora_pmon_db2_abc` ?? I think better sol may be `lastIndexOf('ora_pmon_')` as per OP question...

Comment: You're right, but the OP hasn't noted that there will be such case.